# Error when converting HTML to pdf with jspdf

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

For an Angular project, I am trying to transform a string variable containing HTML code into a pdf file.
I installed all the dependants such as:

- jspdf
- html2canvas
- rasterizehtml

My code looks like this:

```
  b64DecodeUnicode(str) {
    return decodeURIComponent(atob(str).split('').map(function(c) {
      return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
    }).join(''));
  }


  getBill() {
   //var blob = new Blob([this.b64DecodeUnicode(this.invoicePDF)], {type: "text/html;charset=utf-8"});

    var doc = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
   /* doc.text(20, 20, 'Hello world!');
    doc.text(20, 30, 'This is client-side Javascript, pumping out a PDF.');
    doc.addPage('a6','l');
    doc.text(20, 20, 'Do you like that?');
   doc.save('Demo.pdf');*/
    var  htmlData =  String(this.b64DecodeUnicode(this.invoicePDF));
    doc.addHTML(htmlData, function () {
      doc.save('myfilename' + '.pdf');
    });
    //FileSaver.saveAs(doc, "facture_"+this.order.reference+".html");
  }
```

For that I use jspdf, but I get this error:

> core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Supplied Data
>   is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData  Error:
>   Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String
>   jsPDF.convertStringToImageData 
>       at Object.x.convertStringToImageData (jspdf.min.js:50)
>       at Object.x.addImage (jspdf.min.js:50)
>       at Object. (jspdf.min.js:188)
>       at jspdf.min.js:188
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:3820)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:387)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:138)
>       at zone.js:872
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
>       at zone.js:877
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:421)
>       at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
>   (zone.js:420)
>       at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
>       at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask
>   [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
>       at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
>       at Image.globalZoneAwareCallback (zone.js:1566)

How I can fixe it?
Thank you in advance.